# How can remove the last digit in an int (C#)?

Tags: c#

How can I remove the last digit in an int (C#)?

1. I would like to use in c# console, user put 9 digit number and I remove the last digit of number
2. how should I choose some digit from above for example 1234456782 and i choose 2-4-6-8?

Answer (score 15):

You should try to divide it by 10:

```
int number = 123456789;
int newNumber= number/10;
Console.WriteLine("new number: {0}", newNumber);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
int i = 123456789
int newVal = i/10;
```

Answer (score 2):

`num -= num % 10;`

Comment: you will transform 123456 into 123450 this way.

Answer (score 0):

```
int num = 123456;

int numMinusUnitsDigit = 10 * (num / 10);

Console.WriteLine("number without Units digit: {0}", numMinusUnitsDigit );
```

Comment: This won't work if the input is between 0 and 9, in case they enter something other than a 9 digit number.  It will reduce it to the tenths.  Also, your math is wrong.  I think you meant int numMinusUnitsDigit = num / 10;

Comment: @Lane Since, num is integer num=123456/10 gives num=12345, & num =12345*10 gives 123450

Comment: i fail to see why the downvotes. It removes the units digit as requested.

Answer (score 0):

1.

```
string num = input.ToString();
if (num.Length > 1)
{
 num = num.Remove(num.Length - 1, 1);
}
```

2.

```
num = num[1] + num[4] + num[6] + num[8];
```